# Matlab - Trying to use vectors with grid coordinates and value at each point for a color plot

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

I'm trying to make a color plot in matlab using output data from another program. What I have are 3 vectors indicating the x-position, y-yposition (both in milliarcseconds, since this represents an image of the surroundings of a black hole), and value (which will be assigned a color) of every point in the desired image. I apparently can't use pcolor, because the values which indicate the color of each "pixel" are not in a matrix, and I don't know a way other than meshgrid to create a matrix out of the vectors, which didn't work due to the size of the vectors.

Thanks in advance for any help, I may not be able to reply immediately.

Comment: how big are the vectors?

Comment: Have you tried my solution for you?

Answer (score 1):

If we make no assumptions about the arrangement of the x,y coordinates (i.e. non-monotonic) and the sparsity of the data samples, the best way to get a nice image out of your vectors is to use `TriScatteredInterp`.  Here is an example:

```
% samplesToGrid.m
function [vi,xi,yi] = samplesToGrid(x,y,v)

F = TriScatteredInterp(x,y,v);
[yi,xi] = ndgrid(min(y(:)):max(y(:)), min(x(:)):max(x(:)));
vi = F(xi,yi);
```

Here's an example of taking 500 "pixel" samples on a 100x100 grid and building a full image:

```
% exampleSparsePeakSamples.m
x = randi(100,[500 1]); y = randi(100,[500 1]);
v = exp(-(x-50).^2/50) .* exp(-(y-50).^2/50) + 1e-2*randn(size(x));
vi = samplesToGrid(x,y,v);
imagesc(vi); axis image
```

Gordon's answer will work *if the coordinates are integer-valued*, but the image will be spare.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your values to a matrix based on the x and y coordinates and then use imagesc (or a similar function).

```
% Assuming the X and Y coords start at 1
max_x = max(Xcoords);
max_y = max(Ycoords);

data = nan(max_y, max_x); % Note the order of y and x
indexes = sub2ind(size(data), max_y, max_x);
data(indexes) = Values;

imagesc(data); % note that NaN values will be colored with the minimum colormap value
```