# meshgrid visualization for irregularly spaced data

Tags: matlab, octave, matlab-figure

I want to visualize vector G, measured at locations from vector X and Y, spaced irregularly. The meshgrid, surf, countour etc. functions all want a regular meshgrid and much more points from G than I have. How can I do this? plot3 is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

For irregularly spaced samples, you want scattered data interpolation.  See [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796134/matlab-trying-to-use-vectors-with-grid-coordinates-and-value-at-each-point-for/18798669#18798669) on [`TriScatteredInterp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triscatteredinterp.html).  By the way, there is a new object oriented interface called [`scatteredInterpolant`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolantclass.html), but the idea is the same.